# Delete specific array index in session array

Tags: php, session

I am trying to delete an item in my cart.php. It works for the first time. But when i try to delete next item code delete the next item not the one that I am trying to remove. Here's my code:

```
    <?php 
//if user wants to remove any item from cart
if(isset($_REQUEST['index_to_remove']) && $_REQUEST['index_to_remove'] = !"")
{
    $key_to_remove = $_REQUEST['index_to_remove'];
    if(count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1){
        unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
    }else{
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        rsort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        print_r($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: I would suggest to first check if $_SESSION["cart_array"] is set before trying to unset it or any of its values. So change `if(count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1)` into `if(isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You should never `unset($_SESSION)`. The easiest way to clear the `$_SESSION` variable is `$_SESSION = Array();`, 
but you can also iterate with unset: 
`foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) unset($_SESSION[$k]);`

Comment: He doesn't do that to start with, does he ?

Comment: However, he need to use unset(), to remove the session value.

Comment: i need unset() to remove my session value. if u guys need my whole cart.php i'll share that. if it helps. thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
rsort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

output

```
0 = orange
1 = lemon
2 = banana
3 = apple
```

rsort will assign keys dynamically from 0 which is changing your keys.

Comment: yh i know about sort functions but thats not the problem. i already tried without rsort. still the same prob. thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing `session_start()` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: its just part of my code. if you need my whole script then i can do that. i've done session start and everything. thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

thanxs guys for your help i've got the problem. problem was in the if statement my if statement was

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['index_to_remove']) && $_REQUEST['index_to_remove'] = !"")
```

in this statement you if put ! before = it will work fine. so this if statement will looks like this.

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['index_to_remove']) && $_REQUEST['index_to_remove'] != "")
```